# Javascript -- If h2_JSON is an object {} (as shown in my console.log -- why is it falling into the else loop?

Tags: javascript, json

Any ideas anyone - why the logic in my javascript is falling into the "ELse" part of this conditional when my console.log shows that the h2_JSON is an object {}??

```
if (h2_JSON == {})
{
window.location.href ='/coursecatalog/retrieveCourses/1/' + h1key;

}
else
{   
var html_output = "";

for (var key in h2_JSON)                
    {

   html_output += "<a href=\"javascript:gettingLevel3(\'" + h2_JSON[key] + "\')\">" + key + "</a><br />";
   console.log(html_output);        
}
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is that condition intended to check?

Comment: Because `x == {}` is *always* false ..

Comment: I'm trying to check if the h2_JSON returned no results (i.e. an empty dictionary) --- I'm new at this - so sorry if it's a silly question in advance.  How do I check to see whether it has nothing in the dictionary (i.e. no data was returned from server?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `foo == {}` is not a check to see if `foo` is *an* object. It is a check to see if `foo` is ***that*** object. But (in this context) `{}` is an object initializer, so there is no value – not even another empty object – equal to it:

```
var a = {}, b = {};
a == b; // false
```

The condition is **always** false.

If you want to see if something is an object, you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (among other techniques):

```
if (typeof h2_JSON === 'object') {
    window.location.href ='/coursecatalog/retrieveCourses/1/' + h1key;
}
else {
    // snip
}
```

---

> How do I check to see whether it has nothing in the dictionary (i.e. no data was returned from server?)

An object is "empty" if it has no enumerable own properties. [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is your friend here.

```
if (Object.keys(h2_JSON).length) {
    // it's not empty
} else {
    // it is empty
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for taking the time

Comment: You're quite welcome. It helps, of course, if you ask the right question from the get-go.